# Changed TFS 2015 server IP address and now gated checkins won't build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, gated-checkin

My company just decided to move our TFS 2015 server and gave it a new IP and Computer Name. I have fixed some of the resulting issues and can connect to the server, but I cannot get the gated check-in build working again.

I'm getting the following error which shows the old IP:

[image: TFS Build failure output]

I've changed this everywhere I can find. Could someone tell me where this might be coming from?

Comment: Have you updated the agent settings on the agent machine?  What does it say in settings.json?  Is it still pointing at the old server?

Comment: I completely deleted everything having to do with builds that I could and recreated it. The Settings file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Build, had the wrong machine name but I corrected that. Still not working.

Comment: Did you re-install the agent?  Is the agent on a separate machine?

Comment: No and no. I'm not sure how to reinstall that default agent, but I'll look around for that. I'm not much of a TFS expert as you can tell.

Comment: This might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/agents/windows - I'm assuming this is a 2015 build rather than a xaml build

Comment: I've looked that over and couldn't follow along as it doesn't show some of the options I have. Can I be sure that this wrong IP is even in TFS? I found some wrong IPs in my solution files and changed them, but could this be on my machine?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to **your solutions still associate with old server.** The TFS server registration info still stored in Visual Studio.You need to remove the bindings.

You can either edit the sln file manually or just **remove the cache** in `C:\Users[USER]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\X.0\Cache` Then open Team Explorer in VS and add the new server. This will force Visual Studio to use the new IP address that you have changed.